# Can you cache community builders?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-container-registry, google-container-builder

I need to use Helm in my build pipeline. As described in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/cloud-builders) I downloaded the source of the [Helm community builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/helm) and pushed the built image to GCR.

Now if i use the builder in my pipeline it takes an absurd amount of time for Google Build to download the builder image from GCR and run the Helm commands.

Is there any way I could speed this process up? Can I somehow cache intermediate layers of a builder image?

Comment: Hi there! You can use cache as described in [Using a cached Docker image](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/speeding-up-builds#using_a_cached_docker_image) section. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @ArmandoCuevas Well no, not really since I'm not building an image myself, but using a [Community builder](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/cloud-builders#community-contributed_builders) image (in this case Helm). The image of this community builder resides on my Google Container Registry. My build pipeline needs to download and run this image during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

With Cloud Build [community images](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community), there's a (disappointing) requirement that you must build the image for yourself before you may use it.

If you're building the community image every time you use it, it's going to take more time than is possibly necessary.

IIUC, your `cacheing` solution is to disconnect building the community image (and storing it in e.g. a Google Container Registry to which you have access) from using the community image in your Cloud Builds that use the Helm builder.

Comment: Well, I'm already doing that but I wondered if there's a way to speed up the process even more